# Fine Tune Voltage Control for a Car Stereo/Amplifier.

Tags: potentiometer

Okay, I have done a bit of research and haven’t really found what I consider an answer to my entire problem.  I want to be able to control voltage output using a potentiometer, but the input voltage is variable and I need to be able to see the exact output voltage.

So the initial input source would be a car stereo head unit, the output voltage is very sporadic at best, ranges from 0 up to 5 volts based on where the volume knob is.  What I have found is that volume clicks 0-20 give you an output voltage of 0-1.2 volts.  Then 21-31 jump to the 1.3-2.8 range.  Where last 3 clicks have a greater jump in voltage and go 2.9 -5 volts.
The goal of this project is to be able to see the output voltage of the head unit at all volume clicks and then be able to use a potentiometer to fine tune that voltage while being able to see it also.

For example say volume 18 had an output of 1 volt, and this output voltage was able to get me 534 watts out of my amplifier.  Then I turn it down to 17 I now have a voltage of .89 and that was able to get 493 watts out of my amplifier. I know that the input voltage of an amp is directly related to the output voltage.  So ideally you want to match the output of your Head unit to the input of your amp to get the perfect balance.  However what i am trying to achieve is something slightly different.  I am trying to get a specific wattage output from my amp.  So by turning it wide open and adjusting the input voltage i should be able to control the output.

Thinks I know I will need:
-50K linear Pot
-2 M/F/F Y RCA’s  (input from head unit and output to amplifier)
-Volt meters of some kind, unsure what type since there will be no external power source
-If correct a couple resistors to help fine tune voltage (unsure what sizes)

Not sure if there is anything else that would be needed and how to hook everything up. If someone can point me in the wright directing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Audio is a tricky thing.  Power is not related linearly to volume - most volume potentiometers are actually roughly logarithmic.  They call this "audio taper".  That's why your voltage jump increases per "click".

Comment: "I know that the input voltage of an amp is directly related to the output voltage." - most people think of it the other way round.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "match the output of the head unit to the input of the amp".  You don't run the amplified output of the head unit into an amplifier.  You run the pre-amplified signal out of the head unit into the amplifier.  And usually, you set the input gain on the amplifier to match what the head unit is giving you.

Comment: Yes you are correct Chris M.  If i was setting up a vehicle to be able to play at its best i would hook up a o'scope to the output (rca's) and find my max clean volume.  Then i would hook them up them up to the amps and put the o'scope on the output speakers/sub channels and then adjust the gain of the amp to the max output of clean power to the radio.   But in this cases i am not looking for that output.  I am looking at getting a specific output and the only way i can see achieving this is to have control of the voltage coming out of the HU and going into the amp.

Comment: But the head unit should output line-level...about 1Vpp...from the pre-amplifier stage.  Right?  I guess I don't understand why you can't get a specific power output from the external amp just by using the amp's gain controls.

Comment: Do you have a model number for the head unit you're using?  That way I can at least know what we're dealing with.

Comment: Here is my situation.   I have a head unit (brand X) and it is hooked up to a 7k watt amplifier.  I need to get as close to 1000 watts out of the amplifier.  But at volume 18 i see 876 watts, one would guess by simply going up one click i should be close to the 1000 watts i need.  But the voltage out put is to much and that one click spikes me up to 1234 watts.    The HU does not give me any additional control of the voltage to be able to find the specific voltage to get that 1000 watts.  The gains on most amplifiers are not built to do very small increments.

Comment: Head Unit is a Alpine 117.

Comment: How are you measuring this output power? What sort of signal are you using?

Comment: For the head unit voltage we use a Fluke DMM and test directly on the RCA's as we adjust volume.  To measure the amplifier output (wattage) we use a Term Pro Mangum, it incorporates a clamp and probe to measure current and voltage to provide wattage.

Answer (score 1):

Your HU has a pre out signal of 4 volts max into a 10k ohm load. You can use a simple 10k pot to do additional level control between the HU and the amp as shown, assuming that the input impedance of your amp is also around 10k.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7z9wv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Beat me to it.  +1 for exactly what I was going to say, though.

Comment: Okay, is there also a way to hook up small volt meters to this to see the input voltage coming into the pot and the output going to the amp?   Would it be as simple as finding 2 wire volt display and wiring the + to the input and - to the ground and the same with a meter on the output side of the pot.

Comment: Also does the different ohm load rating of the pot dictate the sensitivity of the output.  Meaning will a 10k provide greater control over say a 50k?

Comment: I updated my answer to show the location of a volt meter. Since your audio level varies substantially, you may prefer an analog type meter or a bar graph meter to monitor the level going into the amplifier. The pot value is chosen to best match the output impedance of your HU. Changing it to 50k will not provide better control. You will set the rough range using the HU volume control and then use the pot to find tune it (lower it slightly).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, and thanks for the diagram Glenn